# Diagonalizing zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Consider the matrix $A = 0$ that is diagonalized by the matrix

$$S = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

What is the diagonal matrix?

I'm confused because I thought you could just use the definition $S^{-1} A S = B$, in order to find the diagonal matrix $B$, and I ended up just getting the zero matrix, but I guess this is wrong. Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't they just be 0?

Comment: @EhBabay What?!

Comment: @VedranSego I am asking what his eigenvalues are. Those values are going to be on the diagonals in the matrix A.

Comment: @EhBabay What do the eigenvalues of a similarity matrix $S$ have to do with this? The eigenvalues of $A = 0$ matter here, and they are zero, as Chrispy wrote in his reply to you.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is the $n\times n$ zero matrix $0_n$, it is already diagonal (non-diagonal elements all zero). Any invertible matrix of the appropriate size diagonalizes it, as well.

This is all trivial because $S^{-1}0_nS =0_n$, right?